# What operations are needed to form a multiplication out of three other variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say I have three products of real number variables

ab cd and cb and I want to perform operations on them to turn them into ad. What operations are needed to do this?

ab?cd?cb = ad (? Is an operation and can be more than just two operations if necessary or have more copies of the products if necessary too)

Comment: Have you tried using $\{+,-,\times,\div\}$ in the two position you have marked with "?" to see what happens?  Perhaps you should demonstrate your work for a few of those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this $\,ab\times cd\div bc\,$ you will get
$$
ab\times cd\div bc=\frac{abcd}{bc}=ad
$$
I think it solves the problem.